# Why does this not violate mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function $f(x,y)$ = $(yx^2,y^2)$
If we use the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in the formulation of the mean value theorem, how can I show this example doesn't violate it?

Since $f(0,0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1,1) = (1,1)$, if we take $f(0,0) - f(1,1) = df(a)((0,0)-(1,1))$,
We get that $a = (1/2, (-1 \pm \sqrt{5})/2)$. These points do not lie on the segment between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ which seems to violate the mean value theorem.

Maybe I'm not understanding the multivariable mean value theorem well enough, but could someone provide some insight into this?

Comment: [There is no exact analog of the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: A often-used counter example is $g(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$ which is $2\pi$-periodic, but $g'$ is nowhere zero.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/mean-value-theorem-for-vector-valued-functions.

Comment: Ah, that's really helpful! The extra links are really insightful